# Spring Security dynamic Access Evaluator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, pre-authentication

i Want that Spring security can block accces to dynamic URL changes

http://domain.com//**
shareURL is a ID, the problem i have is that if i access with shareID 1,the program tell me i need to login(ALL OK) but when if i logged try to run shareID 2, the program should tell me again to relogin because is not my session, but now.. the program permit me access this shareID.

how can i block that user change shareID without login?

Too i'm using pre-auth because if especific shareID not require password, the spring security by pass the auth to avoid the login page and inject a fake Auth.
The best problem if this

ShareID  1 (not require password)
ShareID  2 (Require specific password)

if i log with share 1 (auto login without password) i can acces to shareID 2 (because i'm logged) but shouldn't do it.

Spring-security.xml(Only the problem config)
 
    
        
        
        
        
        
-->

```
<!-- Share Authentication Manager-->        

<beans:bean id="shareUserService" class="com.segator.ownline.service.impl.OwnlineShareSecurityService" />
<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
                    ref="shareUserService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter"
            class="com.segator.ownline.controller.config.ShareLinkAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="appControlAuthenticationManager" id="shareAuth">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I think i need a extra configuration that tell spring security that if user change shareID require login, for exemple if i can implement proper method to interceptor-url
exemple

intercept-url pattern="/share/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SHARE') && sameShareIDLogged()"

Sorry for my bad english, i just studing for now.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem adding some properties on  preAuthFilter

```
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="shareAuthenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="checkForPrincipalChanges" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="invalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange" value="true" /> <!--Default true but i put to understand how work-->
```

checkForPrincipalChanges --> If the principal is diferent that the session(in my case principal=shareID, then try to relogin

invalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange--> Generate new Sesion

Now the problem i have is that when i run j_spring_security_check on my share Form Login is redirecting to my default login form